# Is it possible to pass JSON object to ejs renderFile?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'd rather not have to type out each field name of my ejs file. Here is what i'd like to do:

```
let html = null;
EJS.renderFile('./public/views/results.ejs', {JSON_OBJECT}, (err, str) => {
     html = str;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something encapsulated in {} will create a new object.

So in

```
var JSON_OBJECT = {test: "value"};
var obj2 = {JSON_OBJECT}
```

*obj2* will be an object with a property named *JSON_OBJECT*, which in itself has a property *test*.

EJS.renderFile accepts a JSON object as its second parameter. The properties the object can contain are described in the [package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) of ejs.